# WPUF user profile select terms from taxonomy on wordpress using action hook

Tags: wordpress, user-profile, taxonomy-terms, action-hook

I have created a registration form on WPUF so that users can select their region from a taxonomy. The code is loaded on the form using an action hook.
The code loads the terms from the taxonomy in a dropdown and users can select the region.

But I am having an issue saving the selected terms into the custom field on the user profile. Find the code below:

```
function user_region_taxonomy( $form_id, $post_id, $form_settings, $tax, $user_id ) {
$taxterms = get_terms( 'user_region', array("hide_empty" => "0"));
if ( $post_id ) {
    get_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_region_location', true );
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wpuf-label">
        <label>User Region</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpuf-fields">
<select name='user_region_location' id='user_region_location'>
    <option value='' <?php if (!count( $names )) echo "selected";?>>Select Term</option>
    <?php foreach ( $taxterms as $term ) { 
        echo '<option name="user_region_location" value="' . $term->slug . '" selected>' . $term->name . '</option>',"\n"; 
    } ?>
</select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'user_region_hook', 'user_region_taxonomy', 10, 3 );

function update_user_region_hook( $post_id ) {
   if ( isset( $_POST['user_region_location'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_region', $_POST['user_region_location'] );
   }
}
add_action( 'wpuf_after_register', 'update_user_region_hook' );
add_action( 'wpuf_update_profile', 'update_user_region_hook' );
```